# how to add colomns to databse dynamically in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a CRM on Laravel 5.6 and MySQL, in my clients part, I wonder the admin to add as many columns as he needs to database.

For example, a client can have 2 to 20 telephones.

How to can I add this dynamically with a plus icon on front end to generate the inputs, or should I save all in a single column with a long text?

1 more question is what should I do it with AJAX requests on front-end or jQuery would do the job?

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->integer('fax');
        $table->text('adrress');
        $table->integer('telephone1');
        $table->integer('telephone2');
        $table->integer('telephone3');
        $table->integer('telephone4');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here is my migration and to be more exact I wonder to know that should I make 20 columns until `telephone20` or there is any other way to place it as much as the admin needs?

Comment: Why not just make another table for telephones?

Comment: that can be the solution but how can i set the number dynamic ? or can i do it at all ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better for you to create another table to save dynamic fields.

for example, a table named `client_info` contains fields `id,client_id,key,value` :

```
id | client_id | key          | value
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1         | phone_number | +98654123654
 2 | 1         | address      | 9 York Dr. Lorain, OH 44052
 3 | 2         | email        | MichaelKWarren@armyspy.com
 4 | 1         | email        | PhillipSOrtega@dayrep.com
```